# Using built-in GUI tools, how do I partition/format an empty drive (zeroed out)?

Tags: partitioning, disk, disk-utility

so I'm trying to partition/format a zeroed out USB drive using Disks app.

When formatting, it doesn't give me an option to select GPT/MBR. All I get see it an option to select filesystem. I had to install gparted to get what I want.

BUT it's possible, I am doing it wrong too.

Thanks!

edit: command I use to zero out disk: dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX count=1000 bs=1M

Answer (score 2):

If it shows an option to select the filesystem, you're using the partition format option. The disk formatting option is elsewhere:

[image: Hamburger menu with "Format Disk"]

[image: Resulting modal with drop down for selecting GPT/MBR]

It also means the disk isn't "zeroed out". Whatever you did kept the partition table, and probably only affected the partition.

Comment: added command to zero out disk :)

Comment: Was the partition unmounted when you ran that command?

Comment: yes. umount /dev/sdX or umount /dev/sdX1 or 2